# Google Cloud bucket external image not showing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to show in my SSRS report images that are saved in a Cloud Storage bucket.

I added the URL, and I added in the column a function that when clicking on the cell, the image should open up in a new window. Now, when the report finishes, the images from the bucket don't show up - the cell is just empty, but when I click on it, a window then opens up with the image. I can't figure out why it won't show it within the report.

**Clarification:**
The URL that doesn't work is of type:
`http://storage.googleapis.com/sp-test/product/large/4991.jpg?v=7` whereas this image that is also in a bucket, but has a CNAME, does work: `http://gcimages.bla.bla/products/45/005445.jpg?v=90`

See in the attachment, `column 3` is empty, but when I clicked on it, it opens the image in a new tab. `column 4` shows the image within the report (it's also in a bucket with CNAME as above).

[Image from SSRS report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1kSo.png)

Comment: I bet you are running a report that is trying to load an image from an endpoint that requires authentication.

Comment: it seems there is some issue with your GCP billing.

Comment: no, it's a public bucket, doesn't belong to me. furthermore, when i click on it, it opens up the image in a separate tab.